# Подскажите почему правило RewriteRule срабатывает не коректно

Tags: .htaccess, apache-modules, apache2.4

Всем доброе время суток. 
Стоит задача сделать переадресацию на сайте с
*/search/all/azazaza* на */search/?query=azazaza* 
Вроде как бы особых проблем нет правило я написал такое

> RewriteRule ^search/all/* /search/?query=$1 [R=301,L]

Воспользовался для проверки правила вот этим сайтом [вот этим сайтом](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)
При проверки на сайте все ок, переадресация проходит как надо...

Но пишу правило на сервер, и переадресация проходит НО параметры azazaza не передаются, тоесть происходит просто редирект на URL /search/?query= что то съедает azazaza, не пойму что, решил на том же сайте загнать весь .htaccess полностью на проверку ( ну вдруг я что то упускаю... ) нет смотрю, опять все работает как надо на сайте, правельно определяет редирект и параметры передает тоже правельно... но на сервере не работает... подскажите что я упустил из виду?

полный .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^search/all/* /search/?query=$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule ^extlink-(\d+)(.*)$ extlink.php?n=$1&url=$2 [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^extlink(/.*)$ extlink.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь подставить первую группу захвата `$1`, а в регулярном выражении ее нет. Пробуйте так

```
RewriteRule ^search/all/(.*)$ /search/?query=$1 [R=301,L]
```

P.S. В группе захвата может быть и пусто, если к вам пришли по адресу `your.site/search/all/`. В таком случае переадресует на `your.site/search/?query=`.